# js turf check if line is within buffer polygon?

Tags: javascript, turfjs

i wrote this function but it didnot worked

```
function intersectPolyByPolyFC(poly, fcPoly) {
      var fgp = [];
      var bbPoly = turf.bboxPolygon(turf.bbox(poly));
      console.log(turf.bbox(poly));
      for (var i = 0; i < fcPoly.features.length; i++) {
        var bb = turf.bboxPolygon(turf.bbox(fcPoly.features[i]));
        if (turf.intersect(bbPoly, bb)) {
          var int = turf.intersect(poly, fcPoly.features[i]);
          if (int) {
            int.properties = fcPoly.features[i].properties;
            fgp.push(int);
          }
        }
      }
      return turf.featureCollection(fgp);
    }
```

Comment: and also check and give its properties

Comment: `i wrote this function but it didnot worked` - Can you provide more details? What is the error you faced?

Comment: it didnt give any error...but it didnot give me all the line in buffer

Comment: You will need to provide more details, what is it you are looking to achieve using this function? Did you try to log the buffer at various intervals? etc.

Comment: i want to get values from buffer ..within buffer it will give us polyline and polygon values